# How to use POCO with Domain Service Class Dialog?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, poco, wcf-ria-services

I want the Domain Service Class to show my entities so that I can have it generate CRUD for me.  Why is nothing showing up?

Project structure:

EF model sits in class library and
POCO (.tt) sits in another class library

[image]

For now I have manually created the CRUD operations, but I want the dialog to create them.

@Akash Kava: Here is a primary key for one of the pocos:

```
    [DataMember]
    public int CVAdvancementQuotientId
    {
        get { return _cVAdvancementQuotientId; }
        set
        {
            if (_cVAdvancementQuotientId != value)
            {
                if (ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled && ChangeTracker.State != ObjectState.Added)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The property 'CVAdvancementQuotientId' is part of the object's key and cannot be changed. Changes to key properties can only be made when the object is not being tracked or is in the Added state.");
                }
                _cVAdvancementQuotientId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CVAdvancementQuotientId");
            }
        }
    }
    private int _cVAdvancementQuotientId;
```

Comment: Does your POCO entities include "Key" attribute on primary key? Domain Service class will only work on classes with "Key" and IQueryable<>

Comment: I used T4 self-tracking entities template to generate the POCOs from my EF4 model.  The [Key] data annotation (I assume you're refering to) is not placed on the POCO.

Comment: Try modifying your tt file to include Key attribute for your primary key

Comment: Same issue, they still do not show (and yes I did rebuild the project before trying to bring up the dialog again).

Comment: Your context is derived from ObjectContext and does it have ObjectSet<> public properties?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean or where to look...

Answer (score 0):

- Have you changed the `Custom Tool Namespace` for the tt file?
  Also, you'd have to edit the .tt file and chenge the line: `string inputFile = @"$edmxInputFile$”` to e.g. `string inputFile = @"../DAL/Northwind.edmx";`.
- There was a reported bug which is fxed now, you can find more info at [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/543930/add-domain-service-class-wizard-fails-to-discover-my-data-model-entities-if-it-contains-renamed-entities) address.
- You'd have to install the WCF RIA Services Toolkit.  You can find it [here](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/).

Comment: Ya, I'm already using the POCOs and EF in another project within the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

^^ Make your code CodeGenerationStrategy as Default rather than none > delete .tt files from your EF model >> Rebuild >> Entities will show up